# how can I set the size of a directional light in Three.JS?

Tags: shadow, three.js, light

I've added a directional light to my scene, but it doesn't show all the shadow. The shadow gets cut off, just like when the FOV of a spotlight is too small.

When I enable the shadowCameraVisible, i see that my light is like a big box which shows the shadow (which makes sense). The question is: how can I make this 'box' bigger?

Answer (score 11):

Found it! Turns out the shadowcamera has left, right, top and bottom properties:

```
light.shadowCameraLeft = -3000;
light.shadowCameraRight = 3000;
light.shadowCameraTop = 3500;
light.shadowCameraBottom = -3000;
```

If you get pixelized shadows, it means your shadow map (read: memory) is not big enough. Experiment which is the lowest map you need, because this seems to be expensive. Example:

```
 light.shadow.mapSize.x = 2048
 light.shadow.mapSize.y = 2048
```

Comment: Nice find. Thanks. However when I set as big as I need, the shadows become pixelized. Any idea why? From a certain smaller area the pixelization is gone again..Very weird.

Comment: OK, I fixed it. We need to make shadow map bigger. Expensive, but you can tweak it to what you want. `light.shadow.mapSize.x = 2048; light.shadow.mapSize.y = 2048`

Comment: Actually, even just setting the map bigger makes the size bigger also, so I wonder how this really works. Someone, please advize on this.